# .cmd or .bat file to Authenticate(encrypted form) and execute queries(insert/update) on MSSQL server from remote machine?

Tags: sql-server

Please help me to create .cmd or .bat file which will contain code to Authenticate(encrypted form) and execute MS SQL queries(insert/update) on MSSQL DB server from remote machine?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: One question, why?

Comment: we have one requirement... On reception of an infrastructure event we have to trigger .bat or .cmd file and insert particular data in the MS SQL database table. so please help me to create script to do so.